# Query to fetch counting field values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 20 fields.
out of 20, 15 have 3 possible value like 0,NA,1+. i need to write a query to fetch each field count which has value > 0. is it possible to get it in single query.?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php

Comment: @danontheline.. It's just record count. I asked about field-wise count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c1<>'0' THEN 1 END) AS c1_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c2<>'0' THEN 1 END) AS c2_count,
    -- ...
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c15<>'0' THEN 1 END) AS c15_count
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select "column1", count(*) from your_table where value>0
union all
select "column2", count(*) from your_table where value>0
...
... // repeat until column20
```

interesting documentation :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html